# Session Management on Mobile HTML5 application

Tags: php, android, html, cordova

I am working on an app using html5, javascript and jquery in the front-end and PHP in the back-end. I am returning all the data to the front-end in form of json.

I have to port this entire front end to a android application using phonegap

The problem I am facing is this:
In the web environment, the cookies are stored on the client side automatically using PHP which helps in managing the sessions. 
How can I manage sessions in my phonegap application?
 Can I store cookies like I can do on a website? If yes, then how? if No, then what's the alternative?

Answer (score 2):

For Android I guess you can. but as iOS strongly discourage cookies, I think you would better off with HTML5 LocalStorage and Sessionstorage.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html